# Why publish() / connect() works with of() but does not work with custom Subject?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, rxjs6

The following code works as I would expect.
It prints: `1000` after 1 second

```js
const { of } = require('rxjs');
const { publish } = require('rxjs/operators');


const source = of(1000);
const connectable = source.pipe(publish());
connectable.subscribe((v)=>console.log(v))
setTimeout(() => {
    connectable.connect();    
}, 1000);
```

But the following (where I use a Subject) doesn't print anything:

```js
const { Subject } = require('rxjs');
const { publish } = require('rxjs/operators');

const source = new Subject();//Custom subject
const connectable = source.asObservable().pipe(publish());
source.next(1000);

connectable.subscribe((v)=>console.log(v))
setTimeout(() => {
    connectable.connect();    
}, 1000);
```

Same happens if I move `source.next()` directly after `new Subject()`

Why I don't see anything printed in the second case?

Answer (score 2):

There's a big difference in the two examples (of course your custom Subject could be another one).

Creation method `of(1000)` will create an Observable that emits one `next` emission with value `1000` (and then `complete`) **when you subscribe to it**.

Calling `source.next(1000)` will **immediatelly push one `next` emission** with value `1000` down the chain. However, at that point in your example nobody is listening because you subscribe after that so it never prints anything.

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted [this definition](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/publish): `"Returns a ConnectableObservable, which is a variety of Observable that waits until its connect method is called before it begins emitting items to those Observers that have subscribed to it."`. It doesn't say that it buffers also.

Comment: Yeah, the definition is correct but it doesn't queue emissions until you call `connect()`.